Why does my older WiFi adapter not connect to WiFi 6 mesh network?
I upgraded my WiFi network with a Linksys Mesh network (Velop Pro Wifi 6E), and now one laptop does not connect to the WiFi anymore. It doesn't even see the SSID.
The laptop uses an Intel Dual Band Wireless AC-3160 adapter. I know it is fairly old, but 802.11 is supposed to be backwards compatible.
When I check the network with an analyser, I can see the new network shows as 802.11ax, k and v. Unfortunately, there is nothing I can change in the network, because it is set as "Mesh".
Am I right to conclude that this older adapter will never be able to connect to the new network?

It should connect fine. New Wi-Fi generations continue to support the previous generations. Make sure you have the latest drivers from Intel for your card. I seem to recall a few Intel AC client products choked when seeing some AX networks at first until Intel fixed the drivers.

@Spiff I tried updating, but these seems to be no update available for this Intel card or Lenovo laptop.
